# Sorting HashMap according to one Key

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a ArrayList of Hashmap in which I have keys like name,phoneNo,Date,Age....

I want to sort the Hashmap according to Date field.

If I use LinkedHashMap, then also it is not useful as I am getting the values in random way.

I cannot use a object instead of HashMap, because I don't know how many entries I will get. I am dynamically putting keys and values.

Comment: you mean you want to sort the array of hashmaps according to each hashmap's value under some date key?

Comment: Why an array of maps? Why not a single map instead? And why don't you use a `SortedMap`?

Comment: `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` is what you'll use.

Comment: `Collections.sort()`. Write a `Comparator` that does whatever you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a comparator that picks out the value for "Date" in the hashmap, then compares using that.

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
        public int compare(Map<String, Object> map1, Map<String, Object> map2) {
            Date date1 = (Date) map1.get("Date");
            Date date2 = (Date) map2.get("Date");
            return date1.compareTo(date2);
        }
    });
```

**But** this seriously smells like Object Denial.  Why not create a real object for this data?  If this sorting comes up often, you might even make it Comparable.

Comment: I cannot use a object instead of HashMap, because I don't know how many entries I will get. I am dynamically putting keys and values

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing, what If I want to do the sorting according to First name and then Date. I mean I can have multiple entries for same name with different date. So I want to sort acc. to date for a particular name.

Comment: Then just adapt the comparator; if the result of compareTo is 0, do the same for the second field.  You can go on for as long as you like.